# Filtering an Action button on a record based on active User

Tags: lightning, formula-field, filters, action, lightning-page

I am trying to display a Create a Record button only if the user looking at the page is the same user in a related user field.

I currently have a formula checkbox field that is true if the active user is the same as the related user field. It works when used as a filter in a list view, but isn't working for the action button filter on the lightning page layout.

The lightning page layout filters for actions don't allow field-to-field filtering either, so without this workaround I'm not sure how to accomplish this. Any ideas?

"My Record" formula field logic: `$User.Id = Related_User__r.Id`

Lightning page action filter logic: `My Record Equal True`